# How to clone pytest.Item inside function 'pytest_collection_modifyitems'?

Tags: pytest

I want to take an 'item' (pytest.Item) from 'items' array (inside function ‘pytest_collection_modifyitems’) and clone that 'item' and add it to 'items' array back.

If I put below code(without clone), then one item execution failure will show failure for other 'item' also because both are same referrence.

```
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(session, config, items):
    item_1 = items.pop()
    items.append(item_1)
    items.append(item_1)
    yield
```

That's why I want to clone 'item_1' and append to items. So that both will be separate test. One failure will not affect another item. My expectation is as below

```
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(session, config, items):
    item_1 = items.pop()
    # I want this clone_item functionality which should clone the item.
    item_2 = clone_item(item_1)
    item_2.name = "new_testcase_name"
    items.append(item_1)
    items.append(item_2)
    yield
```

For one of my usecase, i need this requirement. The purpose is not to repeat the testcase execution. Purpose is to execute the same testcase on various steps/places, so I will insert the cloned 'item' on various index of 'items' array. 
Some one please guide me how to do this?

Let me explain my requirement. 
     1)   I am writing automation test for upgrade of multiple components. 
      2)   For this, I have to execute group of tests(using pytest marker) before upgrading component-A
     3)   Then I upgrade component-A by executing one testcase. Then again need to execute same group of test again(using pytest marker). (may be few more group of test also)
      4)   Then upgrade component-B by executing another testcase. Then again need to execute the same group of test again (using pytest marker). ( may be few more group of test also)
      I have to repeat this for all available number of components specified in the configuration file. Configuration file will have details of what all components to be upgraded and what all testcases (with marker name) to be executed before and after upgrade of every components.

```
  So, I planed to write code as explained in below step.
  1)  Run pytest CLI by giving root test path(of all test files). So that all the tests are collected by pytest.
  2)  Read the configuration file (which has the upgrade plan) from 'pytest_collection_modifyitems'
  3)  Here items list will have all the test Items.
  4)  Identity which tests to be exuected(from the pytest marker) from the configuration file.
  5)  Filter those tests usign marker name and put it on another items list (called 'final_items_list'). This final_items_list will be returned from this function
  6)  Next, Identify what components to be upgraded from the configuration file. Identity the testcase name(which does this componet upgrade) from the items list and put it on the final_items_list.
  7)  Identity again which tests to be executed after that component upgrade. Now filter those tests using marker name and put it into the final_items_list. Here test items are may be same tests which is collected in step-4. 
  8)  I repeat the same till all components specified in the configuration file.

   Here, the final_items_list will have same Items repeated (means same memory reference of items). So if one item(test) fails, then pytest will mark  'fail' for all all other same items as well. And also facing pytest failures when pytest executing same items again. Thats why, I wanted to clone the Item before adding into 'final_items_list'.

 Do you have any suggestion to achieve this in pytest?
```

Comment: have you tried deepcopy()

Comment: Yes, I tried copy.deepcopy() already and it fails with below error.
   "TypeError: cannot deepcopy this pattern object"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you execute the same test twice (even if you give it another name), it will succeed or fail twice - this does not mean that the tests depend on each other, they just execute the same code. Note also that changing the name does not change the displayed name - that is taken from the node id.

Comment: Thanks Bremen for you reply.
Yes, If I put same test twice on items list, memory referrence of both test will be same. So one test fail will mark both test as failed. 
Node id is the full path of the test to be executed.
You are right. We can change the name of the test (item). 
But, can you please give me more context of what is displayed name where it will be used?

Comment: @AntonShiban Did you ever find a solution or workaround to this?